# Django channels - websocket_disconnect being called in loop

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

I am using Django-channels in order to provide instant notifications when a new instance of a model is created.

For this purpose, I am using django-channels and a SyncConsumer. Everything is working as it should, except the `websocket_disconnect` which is being called in loop n times.

Here is my consumer code:

```
class BaseConsumer(SyncConsumer):

    def websocket_connect(self, event):
        self.send({"type": "websocket.accept"})

    def websocket_receive(self, event):
        # do some stuff here

    def websocket_disconnect(self, event):
        print("websocket_disconnect")
```

Here is the log from my web server:

```
api_1    | websocket_disconnect
api_1    | websocket_disconnect
api_1    | websocket_disconnect
api_1    | websocket_disconnect
api_1    | websocket_disconnect
api_1    | websocket_disconnect
api_1    | websocket_disconnect
api_1    | websocket_disconnect
api_1    | websocket_disconnect
api_1    | websocket_disconnect
```

And this goes on and on until I stop the web server.

This behaviour happens for both when I close manually the connection in the frontend (I'm using Javascript, so I call `ws.close()`) and if I close the browser tab/client.

This doesn't look to me to right behaviour, as I can hear my computer fans working like hell. How can I stop this method from being triggered after the connection is closed? Because the connection itself get closed properly, as I can verify in the javascript `onclose` method, which gets triggered in the frontend only once.

Has anyone else experiences something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for some days and only a few minutes after posting my question on StackOverFlow I was able to find a solution to my problem.

Reading deeper the documentation, I spotted the following:

> When the socket or connection attached to your consumer is closed -
>   either by you or the client - you will likely get an event sent to you
>   (for example, http.disconnect or websocket.disconnect), and your
>   application instance will be given a short amount of time to act on
>   it.
>
> Once you have finished doing your post-disconnect cleanup, you need to
>   raise channels.exceptions.StopConsumer to halt the ASGI application
>   cleanly and let the server clean it up. If you leave it running - by
>   not raising this exception - the server will reach its application
>   close timeout (which is 10 seconds by default in Daphne) and then kill
>   your application and raise a warning.
>
> The generic consumers below do this for you, so this is only needed if
>   you are writing your own consumer class based on AsyncConsumer or
>   SyncConsumer.

(https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/consumers.html?highlight=websocket.disconnect#closing-consumers)

To summarize, in order to properly close a connection, `StopConsumer` needs to be raised.

Hope this answer will solve some headache to others in the future!